# Android Java - Serialize json date from GSON

Tags: java, android, gson, android-volley, date-format

I am having trouble in serializing a json that has a date.

I have looked over a few other questions and they don't seem to help.

This is an sample of the code

`String jsonString = { Date=2016-12-09T11:58:31 }
Gson myGson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
MyClass myClass = myGson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);`

I get the following stack trace

```
Process: com.apacheapps.prang, PID: 22543
                                               com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2016-12-09T11
                                                   at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
                                                   at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
                                                   at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
                                                   at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
                                                   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
                                                   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
                                                   at                                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-12-09T11" (at offset 13)
                                                   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
                                                   at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
                                                   at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
                                                   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689) 
                                                   at                                            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The java.text error is Unparseable date -  "2016-12-09T11" (at offset 13) which makes me think that the date is being cut off at the colon between HH:mm.

I have done the exact same method on a number of times in different activities using the same class and it works fine. This is completely baffling me.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Edit

As pointed out by ΦXocę and Monish, by json uses equals rather than key-val notation.

This is causing the issue.

For brevity I didn't initially explain the complete process. This is how it looks.

The response from the api looks like this

```
 {"Status":true,"RecordsAffected":1,"Message":null,"OperationId":null,"Result":{"ID":2177,"Date":"2016-12-09T12:33:45"},"ErrorCode":0,"ExceptionMessage":null,"ExceptionStackTrace":null,"ExceptionInnerMessage":null,"ExceptionInnerStackTrace":null}
```

This is serialized into a JsonWrapper class

```
public class JsonWrapper{


public Object Result;
boolean Status;

public String getDisplayName() {
    return Result.toString();
}
```

}

getDisplayName returns the below

```
{ID=2177.0, Date=2016-12-09T12:33:45}
```

I then go on to serialize this into the necessary class.

This normally serialises to the standard key-val notation.

Comment: is this all the content of the JsonString: __{ Date=2016-12-09T11:58:31 }__ ???

Comment: BTW Jsons are __Key:Val__ and not __Key=Val__

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: try with String jsonString = { 2016-12-09T11:58:31 }

Comment: By the way, no such thing as a “json date”. JSON has [very few data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example), with *no* support for date-time types. Your string format happens to comply with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

Answer (score 1):

It is working perfectly fine. Your JSON is not valid.

Just change this line

`String jsonString = { Date=2016-12-09T11:58:31 }`

to

`String jsonString = "{\"Date\":\"2016-12-09T11:58:31\"}";`

---

### Working code

```
String jsonString = "{\"Date\":\"2016-12-09T11:58:31\"}";
Gson myGson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
MyClass myClass = myGson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"GSON deserialized date : " + myClass.getDate().toString());
```

Model class :

```
public class MyClass {

    @SerializedName("Date")
    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**Output :**
GSON deserialized date : Fri Dec 09 11:58:31 GMT+05:30 2016